# Undefined Index & Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update mysql data from user input displayed on a table, i have used the following code, even though the name is set and the value is set when i click update the code states "Undefined index: LHA" but as you can see i have declared this along with Work_date, LHA, AAS, LSA, AAH (the fields throwing the undefiend index errors) I also want the unefcted data to remain the same in the mysql database as apposed to settting it to blank! This is the HTML (A while statement to fetch the data to populate the value fields in the html table)

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) { ?> 


<form action='../action.php' method='post'>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
<td>    <input name='car' id='car' value="vv1"><br/><br/></td>
<td>    <select name='Night' id='Night'><option selected='selected' value='no'>No</option><option value='Yes'>Yes</option></select> <br/><br/></td>
<td>    <input class='text' name="Siteid" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Workbook ID']; ?>" /> <br/><br/></td>
<td> <input class='datepicker' name="Work_date" type="text" value="<?php echo date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($row['Work Date'])) ?>" placeholder="Select Date!"/><br/><br/></td>
<td>   <input class='timepicker' name="LHA" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['LHA'] ?>" /><br/><br/></td>
<td>  <input class='timepicker' name="AAS" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['AAS'] ?>" /><br/><br/></td>
<td> <input class='timepicker' name="LSA" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['LS'] ?>" /><br/><br/></td>
<td>   <input class='timepicker' name="AAH" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['AAH'] ?>" /><br/><br/></td>
<td>    <input  name="Bonus" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Bonus']; ?>" />                <br/><br/></td>
<td>    <input  name="Work_Completed" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Work Completed']; ?>" />  <br/><br/></td>
<td>    <input name="BH" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Hours']; ?>" /><br/><br/></td>

<input type='hidden' name='PID' value="<?php echo $row['PID'];?>" />
<td><input type='submit' name='delete_timesheet' value='delete' /></td>
<td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' name='update_timesheet' value='Update' /></td>
</tr>
</form>



<?php 
}
```

**Just to mention my query and field settings work perfectly on XAMPP but not when online, this is my PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['update_timesheet'])) {

$a = $_POST['car'];
$b = $_POST['Night'];
$c = $_POST['Siteid'];
$d = $_POST['Work_date'];
$e = $_POST['LHA'];
$f = $_POST['AAS'];
$g = $_POST['LSA'];
$h = $_POST['AAH'];
$i = $_POST['Bonus'];
$j = $_POST['BH'];

$l = $_POST['PID']; 
$Paid = create_paid($e, $f, $g, $h);

$stmt = "UPDATE data SET  Car = ?, Night = ?, `Workbook ID` = ?,  `Work Date` = ?, LHA = ?, AAS = ? , LS = ? , AAH = ? , Bonus = ?, `Work Completed` =  ?, Hours = ? WHERE PID = ? ";

$y = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
$y->execute(array($a,$b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $Paid, $l));


header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}
```

Comment: I guess $row['LHA'] is empty in your database. Therefore, your $_POST['LHA'] will be empty and it will give you a notice.

Comment: Is it Work_date or Work  Date ? Also back tick **`** all column names

Comment: The sql field or the name ? The sql field in has a space in (I know it shouldnt had to add it to be able to import to our access database, i didnt design it with spaces in field titles delibretly)